# How can I debug a C program on Mac Terminal with GCC?

Tags: c, xcode, macos, gcc

I want to debug the C program on my Mac Terminal. I use "gcc -o deng.c"

P.S: The *path* is right, but it says "No such file or directory".

I have installed Xcode and Commd line already.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define maxn 1000 + 10

int a[maxn];

int main()
{
    int i, j, n, k, first=1;
    memset (a, 0, sizeof(a));
    scanf("%d%d", &n, &k);

    for(i=1; i<=k; i++)
        for (j = 1; j<=n; j++)
            if(j%i == 0)
                a[j] = !a[j];

    for(i=1; i<=n; i++)
        if(a[i])
        {
            if(first)
                first = 0;
            else
                printf(" ");
            printf("%d", i);
        }

    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `gcc -o deng.c`?  Bye bye source code...

Comment: What is *"Commd line"*? In *"I have installed ... Commd line"*

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`-o` specifies the output file.  That's not what you want here. You probably meant to run

```
gcc -g deng.c
```

The `-g` tells the compiler to include debugging symbols.  The binary is called `a.out` (and you can change the program name to `deng` by running `gcc -g deng.c -o deng`)

To actually run the program, you have to run `./a.out` (or `./deng`, if you ran gcc with -o deng).

To debug the program, you run `gdb a.out` (or `gdb deng`) and then type `run`.  For more help on gdb, [read the documentation](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/)

Comment: And to run it, you must type `./deng` or `./a.out`.  The dot and slash are important.

Answer (score 15):

You need to use lldb, the substitute of gdb on Mac,

```
gcc -g deng.c -o deng
lldb ./deng
```